# After installing SharePoint, Access Denied Error coming [see image]

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, installation

I have installed SharePoint and after installing when I try to access Central Administration I am getting the error-

```
'Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

[image]

I have MySQL installed on same server and I think it could be the error due to that because when I tried to stop the service of MySQL the following error started coming-

```
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

[image]

Can anybody explain how can I resolve this issue. I am stuck at this.

Thanks.

Comment: are you installing the SharePoint on SQL server or MYSQL?

Comment: I want to install it on SQL server. But on the server both SQL server and MySQL is installed.